# remove numerical characters from a string with which contains both numbers and letters from a column (in R)

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains a column in that format. I would like to remove the numbers. Any ideas?

```
    id
1   athens56
2   corfu78
3   london234
.
.
.
150 barcelona2345
```

Comment: Try `gsub('\\d+', '', x)` where `x` is your column

Comment: `transform(data, id = trimws(id, "right", "\\d"))`